# "Wie heißt deine Schwester?" or "Wie heissen?"

Tags: grammar, difference

Which of the following are correct if I want to know the name of Patrick's sister.

> Wie heißt deine Schwester?
>   Wie heißen deine Scwester?

If they are both correct, could you explain how each is different?

Answer (score 2):

Correct is, of course, "heißt" - and only that. The verb "heißen" conjugates in the present tense singular like that:

- ich heiße
- du heißt
- er/sie/es heißt

and in plural:

- wir heißen
- ihr heißt
- sie heißen

You need to you use the singular form here, because the "sister" is only singular. If Patrick had more than one sister, and if you'd be asking "what are the names of Patrick's sister**s**", then

> Wie heißen deine Schwester**n**?

would be correct.

Note: a good - but certainly not the only - online conjugator for German verbs is catus2000.de - [here](http://conjd.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=heissen&var=1).